# How to prevent password reuse using B2C Custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I would like to customize the password policy for my B2C Custom Login Flow. I can see how to change things like password length etc (see [Password Polices](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-password-complexity-custom))

But I also want to prevent the user from using any of the last 8 passwords. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do with built in functions is: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-reset-not-last-password

For more than last password history, the only workaround is to store the hashes yourself and use a REST API to examine the hash against the new password being provided. Something that we dont recommend doing, and rather using better techniques such as MFA.

Comment: It would be helpful if you please share a snippet of the custom policy where we can send the current password to an API endpoint (that writes the current password to a list if not in the list of passwords previosly used, or returns an error message indicating that the password is repeated), and process the received response within the policy.
P.S. Only the custom policy snippet should suffice (API code snippet not needed)

Comment: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-history

Answer (score 1):

This capability is currently not supported in Azure AD B2C.
[Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/34839976-aadb2c-password-history-policy) is the feedback, please go and upvote this.